# Workplace Stack Exchange - Top User Swag (With A Surprise!)

Tags: discussion

As a thank you for *being awesome* by working so hard to launch a successful site, if you are on page 1 or 2 of:

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all

... I'll be reaching out to you this week to get your information to send you a little care package. What's in this special package for us, you ask? Well I'm *glad* you asked, because I'm about to <strike>tell</strike> show you.

#### Sticker Packs!

[image: Sticker Packs]

#### T-Shirts!

[image: T-Shirts]

#### And a surprise item, RED STAPLERS!

[image: Don't lose this one]

If you aren't on the list, don't despair - we've got some stuff in reserve for events, and now that you're fully graduated you'll probably see me drop in a few times a year for some fun & impromptu contests here on Workplace Meta.

Thank you again to *everyone* that helped make this site a success, and I'll be in touch with you soon!

**Update (3/24)**

I got a bit backlogged last week, I'll be contacting folks today and tomorrow (no, you didn't miss an email).

Comment: Woohoo! I want the coffee maker! :D

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, SE!

Comment: Hey Swag-master Tim, thanks for the recognition -- a lot of our users are international, is this no problem for sending swag?

Comment: @jmac we ship swag internationally.

Comment: @Jin, our many international members will be thrilled. This is really a great surprise!

Comment: This is very spiffy!

Comment: Sigh.  Page 3.... *waaah*

Comment: It... was... worth it!!!!

Comment: Damn, as someone on the third page I wish I had done a bit more to get on the second :(

Comment: Excellent. At last, my own red stapler.

Comment: Have you reached out yet? I haven't received any communications either in my StackExchange account or my email address?

Comment: @JimG. I will be today or tomorrow, I got a bit backed up last week.

Comment: Sweet! this is cool :)

Comment: [I complained about my colleauges' odours in a public forum](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/621/48), and all I got was this lousy t-shirt. /couldn't resist

Comment: I believe you have my stapler...

Comment: @Rarity- Listen, we need some room up here, so... if you could just move downstairs, that'll be great

Comment: @TimPost Is there a way one could track the shipment ?

Comment: I *love* that my red stapler contains *red staples*!  Great attention to detail!  (And now I will carefully consider which items merit the special staples...)

Answer (score 15):

I thnk our top person should get something extra in her packet. @bethlakshmi really deserves it.

Answer (score 8):

Just got my package today - very well done! Thanks!

Comment: And red staples in the red stapler!  That's beyond cool.

Comment: seriously? (checks) That is beyond cool! Will save them for special stapling opportunities.