# How about a swag-yielding event?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I started contributing to TWP recently and liking the community so far.

I searched the meta for any past swag-yielding events, and [got a reference for the only one swag giveaway](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2451/61983).

Asked around in chat (Water cooler), seems folks who are around for couple of years also did not see any such events in past, either.

Given the fact

1. I wish to have my hands on some TWP swag
2. It's long due and will help promote the community.
3. The new-ish members also will get to interact and know each others outside the limited participation in chat room.
4. Since motivation wears off, it'll help the veteran participants stay motivated.

I'd like to propose an event which will eventually result in having some form of TWP swag.

It should not / need not be a simple giveaway like the last time, we can have some sort of contest / question opened (like we had for 10M question or 10th. B'day) and eligibility will be the participation and up-voted answer - everybody wins!

Ideas / comments / suggestions ?

Comment: When I reached 250,000 points, I got an email offering some swag and asking me where it should be sent. I replied. That was over 2 months ago, but still no swag. Oh well.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I reached 100k on another site in December and haven't yet gotten the email.  I think there's a bit of a swag logjam right now (in part because they're changing vendors).

Comment: In meta, downvotes means disagreement - so I am to think people actually do not like the idea of getting swag? Hm, that'd be interesting. :)

Comment: Did this (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321399/announcing-our-amazing-2018-stuff-a-way) not qualify?  I got some TWP swag just a couple of months ago (because it does take a bit of time to send it out).

Comment: i love swag and would proudly display sticker on my laptop

Answer (score 4):

I like swag.  And SE sometimes has swag contests (on Meta.SE), so there's precedent.  Communities sometimes even have their own contests with swag prizes (Writing did this recently).

There are some hurdles, though:

1. SE is no longer producing new site-specific swag.  This is why Worldbuilding, with its beautiful site design and *hints* of swag, never got it.
2. But Workplace *had* swag, so maybe that's easier?  SE just divested itself of most of its remaining swag (some through a contest on Meta) because they're changing providers, so I don't know if our t-shirts and little red staplers can even be gotten any more.
3. But maybe we could make our own?  We'd need SE's permission, which is possible (Worldbuilding is currently gearing up to make its own swag).  More importantly, somebody has to *pay* for it, including international shipping.  (Worldbuilding is *selling* swag, and for the contest on Writing, SE donated some swag and a patron from within the community paid for shipping.)

Swag is cool but requires some effort and money.  If anybody wants to step up and organize something, go for it!  You probably want to start with some discussions about what people would like, both for the swag and for the contest (if it's a contest).

Comment: Thanks for chiming in! Before getting into the discussion, I'd wait to see the community reaction.

Comment: @SouravGhosh and Monica, what kind of swag do you think would be feasible? Stickers? Mugs? ... is there a link where the past swag that was available is listed (those tshirts and staplers you mentioned)?

Comment: @DarkCygnus [this](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2451/325) was the top-user-swag announcement.  Stickers would be inexpensive to mail, for what that's worth.

Comment: @MonicaCellio thanks for the link. I like the stickers idea. Going further, I *guess* that the images/templates of the stickers could be shared, so anybody can print or make their own stickers in their country with their sticker-maker of preference... no mail or fund raising needed, but the downside is that no event also..

Comment: @DarkCygnus stickers are cheap enough to mail that it shouldn't be a problem for somebody to make them centrally and distribute as part of an event.  Someone who wants to do this should contact SE, both for permission (it's their art) and to see if they have masters or something that could be used to make more.

Comment: @MonicaCellio well, here in my country there are a couple of sticker-maker companies that I know... although I ignore about the feasibility of mailing things from my country to others...